MS Access Expression Question Getting Granular with Expression Selection
I need help building an expression in MS access. I know the basics but I've not done a complicated expression before.
The database is something that gets data like labor and materials from jobs and marks them up to what we charge the customer. I have figured out the labor side, but the material side is more complex. The current formula is this:
Material Cost: IIf([MATERIAL_TYPE]="S" Or [MATERIAL_TYPE]="M",[MATERIAL_COST]*1.42,[MATERIAL_COST])

What I need to do is add a new material type into the equation ([MATERIAL_TYPE]="T") but only when [MATERIAL_TYPE]="T" is from accounts 5, 6, or 7. How do I do this?
I've tried this expression but the syntax is not correct.
Material Cost: IIf([MATERIAL_TYPE]="S" Or [MATERIAL_TYPE]="M" Or ([MATERIAL_TYPE]="T" where [ACCT = "5" "6" "7"]),[MATERIAL_COST]*1.42,[MATERIAL_COST])

Sample data:
Product 1 (Material Type S, Account 4)  
Product 2 (Material Type S, Account 5)  
Product 3 (Material Type M, Account 2)  
Product 4 (Material Type M, Account 6)  
Product 5 (Material Type T, Account 6)  
Product 6 (Material Type T, Account 9)  
Product 7 (Material Type T, Account 1)

Using the sample data I'd want the first 5 products selected, but not the last 2, if that makes sense.

Please include MATERIAL_COST in your sample data

Since you want to exclude products 6 and 7 you can put your conditions in a WHERE clause instead of an IFF.  SELECT [MATERIAL_COST]*1.42 AS Cost FROM table WHERE [MATERIAL_TYPE]="S" OR [MATERIAL_TYPE]="M" OR ([MATERIAL_TYPE]="T" AND ACCT in ("5", "6", "7") )

Since you want to exclude products 6 and 7 you can put your conditions in a WHERE clause instead of an IFF.
SELECT [MATERIAL_COST]*1.42 AS Cost 
FROM table 
WHERE [MATERIAL_TYPE]="S" 
   OR [MATERIAL_TYPE]="M" 
   OR ([MATERIAL_TYPE]="T" AND ACCT in ("5", "6", "7") )


Is it possible to use this in part of the query designer? There are several other fields here as well. My options here are "Field" "Table" "Total" " Sort" Show" "Criteria" and "Or". Currently the provided formula is in the "Field" field and "expression" is selected in "Total" and "show" is checked. I've never seen a SQL statement like yours in the "field" field.

@Grant The text after WHERE is considered Criteria. Or you can right click in the grey background above that grid of options and select SQL view. work directly with the raw SQL statement instead of plugging in parts of it in a grid.
